Power BI change slicer logic from OR to AND
I have a table that looks like this:
| Person ID |  Date |  Day     | AM/PM |
|-—---------|-—-----|-—--------|-—-----|
|  1        | 5/6/24|   Friday | am    |
|  2.       | 5/6/24|   Friday | pm    |
|  2.       | 8/6/24|   Monday | am    |
|  3.       | 5/6/24|   Friday | am    |
|  4.       | 8/6/24|   Monday | am    |

I have a slicer that allows me to select two or more options, for example Friday PM and Monday AM.
This returns a row for all of the items that have a Friday PM and Monday AM.
What I want is only the items whose person ID meet both criteria: both Friday PM AND Monday AM.  I am also getting rows for items that only have one of the criteria. This seems to imply the filter uses OR logic where I want AND logic.  Is there anyway of configuring this effect.
I cannot filter the table as I need to return all the items from the database as sometime I may need to have different criteria ie Thursday AM and Tuesday AM.
Desired Output
In this scenario I only want to return ID 2 as it has both Friday pm and Monday am.
| Person ID |  Date |  Day     | AM/PM |
|-—---------|-—-----|-—--------|-—-----|
|  2.       | 5/6/24|  Friday  | pm    |
|  2.       | 8/6/24|  Monday   am    |

This table on the report is generated via the drop down menu and has several hundred rows with many repeated IDs but there will only ever be 2 IDs one for Friday and one for Monday in this example.

How are these two tables related? Did you create a new column merging Weekday and Time for both of them?

No, there is only one table containing the rows specified

Would it be possible to merge the Day and AM/PM columns into one in order to filter that column?

Also, this is only possible if your output table only has the UserID. If you add more columns like Day, Date and so on the AND filter won't display those. "Monday pm AND Friday am" will work for ID 2, since it's the same for both rows, but it won't work for the other columns and won't display anything.

Instead of editing an answer, please comment with the same account you posted this question with.

I tried to but I got an error that said I need 50 points before I could comment and I didn’t want just ignore the kind offer of assistance.  Apologies

First, create a new column by merging the two columns containing the Weekday and Time period. 
For this example, I called this column Weekday_Time.

After this, create a measure that will be used as a filter on your visual.
IsUserFiltered = 
VAR _numberOfWeekdays = 
    IF(ISFILTERED(Users[Weekday_Time]), COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(Users[Weekday_Time])), 0)

RETURN 
    IF(_numberOfWeekdays = 0, 
        1,
        IF(DISTINCTCOUNT(Users[Weekday_Time]) = _numberOfWeekdays, 1, 0))

This measure will check if the Weekday_Time column is filtered, and display all data if it isn't. 
If the Weekday_Time column IS filtered, it will return 1 for users whose Weekday_Time matches the ones selected.
Now add this measure as a filter in your visual with the condition IS 1:

Since your visual will be using AND logic instead of OR, it is important to remember that it will only show data as long as the rows match. 
This means that if, for example, you choose Monday PM and Tuesday AM on your slicer and your table visual only has the UserId, it will display ID 1 since it matches both conditions (AND). 
If your table visual has more columns, it won't display any data, since the UserId will match both conditions, but the other columns won't (Monday PM doesn't match both Monday PM AND Tuesday AM).


This doesn’t seem to work. When I use the measure I get every pupil against the first ID, then every pupil against the second ID repeated for the whole dataset.  The IDs are 6 numbers long, does this makes any difference?  Also when I add the Weekday_Time column to the report table all the data vanishes leaving an empty table.  If I add the measure I get a column of 1’s and the duplication shown above.

As explained in the answer, you can't add those columns to the table or the data won't show since they don't match both conditions. The measure should work if used properly as shown in my example.

I must have miss understood, will this give me a list of IDs that can then use to generate a table that will show the pupils information?

If you have the date column on your table and filter for both Monday AND Tuesday, you won't get any results, since Monday doesnt equal Monday AND Tuesday

That has worked, I just need to double check the data and we should be good to go.  Many thanks

I want to accept this as an answer but it isn’t letting me. ‍♂️

then you can create a new column
Column=
VAR _fp =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ID] )
                && 'Table'[Day] = "Friday"
                && 'Table'[AM/PM] = "pm"
        ),
        'Table'[Day]
    )
VAR _ma =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ID] )
                && 'Table'[Day] = "Monday"
                && 'Table'[AM/PM] = "am"
        ),
        'Table'[Day]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( _fp <> "" && _ma <> "", "y" )


then create a filter to set the column = "y" to get the ID 2.

Thank you for this but this still hard codes the days into the table.  Sometimes the first and last days of the school week are different, hence the drop down ie one week it might be Thursday pm and Monday am. I think this all has to happen on the report surface as the choices are made via the drop down menu? I know it’s some sort of filter but it I need the menu to return AND logic but the drop down returns OR.

Could a column be generated that returns unique IDs and then deletes/hides them?  I have looked into this but there doesn’t seem to be a UNIQUE operator like in Excel

could you pls update the sample data and expected output? looks like the logic is not 100% the same as what you mentioned. If the logic can't be elaborate clearly, then it's not easy to provide the solution.

Hi Ryan. I have added the expected outcome, there is some duplication which I would eventually like to get rid of so only one row for each student is visible but this would give the users some idea as to who was absent on the two days

the output is displaying two rows of ID2 which is the same as what I mentioned. if you select column ="y", you will get the output of id2.

Yes but the data for Friday and Monday is coded into the code.  Some weeks the last day of the week might be Thursday or the first day of the week might be Tuesday.  The user needs to be able to select these options and see the pupils that meet these criteria

still not very clear about this. When the last day of week is Thursday or the first day of week is Tuesday?  How to identify these special days? The users want to select these days as well? Then I think we need to flag these special days as well. So you need to elaborate the whole logic.

I think @AllanK wants to be able to pick any combination of day/time, so the combinations can't be hardcoded, and the filter should act like an AND instead of an OR, which is the default behavior

you can try to create a new column
Column 2 = 
IF (
    'Table'[week] = "Monday"
        && 'Table'[column] = "AM"
        || 'Table'[week] = "Friday"
        && 'Table'[column] = "PM",
    "Friday PM and Monday AM"
)



Thanks for this but if the criteria are hard coded into the table I cannot change the days to Thursday PM and Tuesday AM for example.  I could make a lot of columns but that would mean one column for each possible permutation.  I have edited the original post to try to clarify the question

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output

I have added a mock table to the original question.
